# Passing URL to PHP web crawler, prints out the link with unnecessary Apostrophes

Tags: php

I have this web crawler which works fine for the given site. 
After extracting the links from the site to my php page, it posts it as text with hyperlink to it.

But the problem here is, the extracted link from the site is partial. so i have to add scheme like "http://example.com/". But when i add this to the extracted link, it prints out in  my php page along with some Unnecessary Apostrophes. which messes up with the link.

the code goes as::

```
<?php
    function get_datac($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }
    $returned_content = get_datac('http://www.usmle.net/step-1/');
    $first_step = explode( '<body' , $returned_content );
    $second_step = explode('</body>', $first_step[1]);
    $third_step = explode('<ul>', $second_step[0]);
    // print_r($third_step);
    foreach ($third_step as $key=>$element) {
    $head = 'http://example.com';
    $child_first = explode( '<li' , $element );
    $child_second = explode( '</li>' , $child_first[1] );
    $child_third = explode( '<a href=' , $child_second[0] );
    $child_fourth = explode( '</a>' , $child_third[1] );
    $link = $head.$child_fourth[0];
    $final = "<a href=".$link."</a></br>";
?>
<li target="_blank" class="itemtitle">
    <span class="item_new"></span><?php echo $final?>
</li>
<?php
    }
?>
```

here, the link prints out as 
`https://example.com/"extractedlink/"`

the above shown extra apostrophes are breaking the link to error.

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the tag will either be `<a href="/link">` or `<a href='/link'>`.  Your code is correctly extracting the `"/link"` or `'/link'` parts, so they simply need removing.

This can be done using the `trim()` function within PHP, such as:

```
$head . trim($child_fourth[0], '\'"'); // build the link 
$final = "<a href=\"".$link."</a></br>"; // add the link into the $final variable
```

That will replace both `"` and `'` from each end of the `$child_fourth[0]` variable so cover both cases.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but it gave me an error as `trim() expects at most 2 param, 3 givem`

Comment: @harishk I've updated it.  I was thinking of a different function when typing this out.

Comment: now it says, `trim expects param 2 be string, array given`

Comment: @harishk I've replaced the array of characters (again for a different function) with a string of characters to replace.  I'm no longer sure that this will work though.

Comment: well it kinda gave a hickup... it gave me link but instead of double apostrophes, it gave single apostrophe on the end of link.. like     `https://example.com/ggggg/ddd/"` which kinda directed to URL error.. can you help me with this...

Comment: why didn't it removed both apostrophes, instead leaving one?

Comment: That issue is going to come down to how you're splitting the links out.  They are going to be in the format `<a href="/ggg/ddd">link text</a>` which, when you're splitting out, is leaving you with `"/ggg/ddd">link text</a>`, and then the trim leaving you with `/ggg/ddd">link text</a>`.  What you probably need to do is change `$head . trim($child_fourth[0], '\'"');` to `$head . '"' . trim($child_fourth[0], '\'"');`.

Comment: It only removed one apostrophe instead of both you expected because `trim()` only works on the start and end of a string.  Anything else at that point would run the risk of breaking a link if there was something like `<a href="/ggg/ddd" class="first-class second-class" title="This is a link title">Link Text</a>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135698/discussion-between-harishk-and-gabe3886).